# Send JSON list via GET Request

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-mvc-5

I am attempting to speed up the process of my local software sync. Right now we send a GET requested for each individual record that we need and the API sends back a JSON string containing that records data, which is then inserted into the local database. This all works, however it can be tediously slow. I am trying to speed this up, and was hoping a good way to do so would be to send a JSON of `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`. This would make it so that I can request much more data in one shot on the API side, add it to the list, and pass it back as JSON to the local machine.

Right now on the local side I have:

```
Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    string basicAuth = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", usr, pwd)));

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basicAuth);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    string requested = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tableList);

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(syncUrl + hash + "/" + requested).Result;

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // get the error
        StreamReader errorStream = new StreamReader(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result, enc);
        throw new Exception(errorStream.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

My Controller call looks like this:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[Route("getRecords/{hash}/{requested}")]
public HttpResponseMessage getRecords(string hash, string requested)
```

Whenever I make this call it gives me an error that it cannot find the URI and I don't even hit my breakpoint on my API. How do I get this to work, or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm doing?

Comment: How do you expect us to know whether the Url you are passing is correct or not if you don't post it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to urlencode the data, if there is any special url chars (like ampersand or slash) it will render unusable the data, so you must urlencode it to be rightly formatted.

Use something like...

```
string requested = Uri.EscapeDataString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tableList));
```

This will encode the special chars so them can be transferred securely on the URL.